# Access to opened PDF in Browser from Java Script

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf

I have a requirement to upload PDF file to a server after reviewing it in Browser. How can I get access to a file I download and view in Firefox and embeded Acrobat Reader ? or maybe I must create script for Acrobat Reader which will manege him to upload the file ?

Answer (score 0):

A firefox plugin can access the url and send it to a server. the server can get the PDF if it is on the same or another server.
It can however not upload the file from file system unless the user helps with filling in an upload file field. This is for security reasons.

When you mention an Acrobat script, are you thinking of making the pdf upload itself? Or are you referring to scripting the reader itself?